# Using Select2 multi-checkboxes JS Plugin to show-hide table data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use Wasikuss's Select2 multi-checkbox (https://github.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/) to hide the table column's basis the options that are unchecked from the dropdown.

The 'class' of each option in the dropdown corresponds to the class of the 'td' of the column to be hidden.

The JQuery that I'm using to do this is basically identifying the deselected option (aria-selected=false) and using the last element of the option id (which matches with the class of the corresponding column 'td's) to identify and hide the required column:

```
$("#select2-ColumnCheckbox-results .select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]").each(function () {  
    var ToHide = $(this).attr("id").split('-').slice(-1)[0];
    var column =  ".CompTable table ." + ToHide;
    $(column).hide();
});
});
```

While the multi-select checkbox is working, but the column show-hide is not working as expected, not sure where I'm going wrong with it.

Following is the complete code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery('#ColumnCheckbox').select2MultiCheckboxes({
    width: '50%'
  })

  $("#select2-ColumnCheckbox-results .select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]").each(function() {
    var ToHide = $(this).attr("id").split('-').slice(-1)[0];
    var column = ".CompTable table ." + ToHide;
    $(column).hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.select2-results__option .wrap:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: #999;
  content: "\f096";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] .wrap:before {
  content: "\f14a";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/master/select2.multi-checkboxes.js"></script>

<select id="ColumnCheckbox" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected name="Samsung" class="Samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option selected name="Apple" class="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option selected name="Xiomi" class="Xiomi">Xiomi</option>
</select>
<br></br>
<table class="CompTable">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th class="Samsung">Samsung</th>
    <th class="Apple">Apple</th>
    <th class="Xiomi">Xiomi</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Parameter1">
      <td class="Parameter1">Parameter1</td>
      <td class="Parameter1 Samsung">500</td>
      <td class="Parameter1 Apple">300</td>
      <td class="Parameter1 Xiomi">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Parameter2">
      <td class="Parameter2">Parameter2</td>
      <td class="Parameter2 Samsung">300</td>
      <td class="Parameter2 Apple">500</td>
      <td class="Parameter2 Xiomi">700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Parameter3">
      <td class="Parameter3">Parameter3</td>
      <td class="Parameter3 Samsung">900</td>
      <td class="Parameter3 Apple">200</td>
      <td class="Parameter3 Xiomi">500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please do let me know where I'm going wrong with this. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Can you replace your script with the below change event?

    $("#ColumnCheckbox").change(function() {
        var options = $(this).find("option");
        $.each(options,function(i,val){
            var selected = $(this).prop("selected");
            var currentClass = $(this).attr("class");
            if(selected == false){
                $("table.CompTable thead  th." + currentClass).hide();
                $("table.CompTable tbody tr td." + currentClass).hide();
            }else{
                $("table.CompTable thead  th." + currentClass).show();
                $("table.CompTable tbody tr td." + currentClass).show();
            }
        });
```